# Regular expression to parse xml in .net

Tags: .net, xml, regex, vb.net

I have the following function that I am using to remove the characters **\04** and **nulls** from my xmlString but I can't find what do I need to change to avoid removing the \ from my ending tags. This is what I get when I run this function

```
<ARR>20080625<ARR><DEP>20110606<DEP><PCIID>626783<PCIID><NOPAX>1<NOPAX><TG><TG><HASPREV>FALSE<HASPREV><HASSUCC>FALSE<HASSUCC>
```

Can anybody help me find out what do I need to change in my expression to keep the ending tag as **`</tag>`**

```
Private Function CleanInput(ByVal inputXML As String) As String
    ' Note - This will perform better if you compile the Regex and use a reference to it.
    ' That assumes it will still be memory-resident the next time it is invoked.
    ' Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
    Return Regex.Replace(inputXML, "[^><\w\.@-]", "")
End Function
```

Comment: This does not remove `'\0'` and `'\04'` characters from your string, but rather removes everything except a few characters (`<`, `>`, whitespace, `.`, `@` and `-`). Also, what is the input that gives the output that you mention?

Comment: Can you post a line or two of what the input to this function looks like?

Comment: @Thomas, `\w` is word characters, not whitespace.

Comment: Whoops! Which once again proves than regexes were made to be written, not read ;)

Comment: +1 for coming up with a case where using regular expressions and XML together was not a WTF. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Private Function CleanInput(ByVal inputXML As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(inputXML, "[^/><\w\.@-]", "")
    ' --------------------------------^
End Function
```

But since your target is only removing the `\04` and `\00`'s it's safer to restrict the replacement on them only.

```
Private Function CleanInput(ByVal inputXML As String) As String
    Return Regex.Replace(inputXML, "[\4\0]", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! everybody for your input. I am getting a clean XML now.